# Tax as an Italian resident

Tags: usa, taxes, citizenship, residency, italy

I am a US citizen in Italy and just submitted my documents for dual citizenship.  I have residency in the Comune where I am applying. I will now be returning to the US.  I was told I need to keep the residency until my citizenship application is accepted.  On another forum I was told that I am liable for taxes on my US assets while I have my residency in Italy.  Is this correct information?  Do I need to keep the residency until I get my Italian passport?  Also can I apply for the AIRE online from the US?  Thank you, and sorry if these questions have already been addressed.  Theresa